# Does a Shepherd Druid's Mighty Summoner apply to creatures transformed by polymorph?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, summoning

Does the language used in the Mighty Summoner feature, "Summoned OR Created", allow the ability to apply to a player transformed by polymorph?

Does *[polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph)*, which reads, "This spell transforms a creature that you can see within range into a new form", count as *creating* a beast?

Answer (score 7):

#### A Polymorphed creature is still the creature.

To determine if a creature was “created or summoned” by a spell we ask the question:

> was this creature here before the spell was cast?

Now, say I cast *polymorph* on Jim. Was Jim here before the spell was cast? Yes. I have not created Jim, I have not summoned Jim. Jim’s been here the whole time. Mighty Summoner does not apply to Jim.

Answer (score -1):

### No

[Polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph) is a Transmutation spell. It doesn't summon or create anything; it transforms one thing into a different thing.